# Simple server for two players given a URL

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to implement a browser based game via php that can be played by two players remotely given a unique game ID
so that e.g.  http://example.com/game.php?id=112

My concern is, how are they going to take turns alternatively?
also, how would i implement the server so that it can only be played via that unique ID only?

Heres what i have thought of so far

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
   <script type="text/javascript">
 window.onload = function() {
  //var turn = confirm("It's your turn!");
  var turn = true;
  if (turn == true) {
    var okPressed = confirm("It's your turn!");
    if ( okPressed == true) {
      // start player's turn
    }
  }
   </script>
 </head>
 <body>
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['player1'] = true;
    $_SESSION['player2'] = false;
  ?>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: You can't store both players' sessions in the same session var. You'll need to keep track of both players on the server, in a database or the filesystem.

Comment: well how would you construct such a server?

Comment: This looks like something to get you started: http://buildnewgames.com/real-time-multiplayer/